# Rendering: Excluding a layer while keeping it's influence (Masking?)

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers, masking

I am making this Christmas Tree but the problem is that I can't render the whole scene in one go because of too many particles. So I have rendered my tree and now I want to render only tinsels wrapped around the tree but I want it as png with alpha so that I can add them together as layers.
So how can I do this?
Thanks.

Tree
[image: Tree]

Tinsel
[image: Tinsel]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. Can you write it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you replace the transparent with a holdout shader. However that doesn't solve the Memory issue. 
There's a fairly easy solution, which of course doesn't work in all cases.
In post you can use the Z-pass in order to combine renderlayers. 
Compositor -> SHIFT A -> Color -> Z-Combine.
It is intended to do what you want, but it will produce strange results when MB or DoF is involved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An example would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you get the notification that I edited my original answer as for your request?

Answer (score -1):

In my own opinion the only way do so in Blender 2.8* is to override the **hidden but influencing** materials with Camera ray to Transparent setup:

[image: hidden but influencing]
Diffuse BSDF must be replaced with your Node setup.

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't seem to be working. A example would be really helpful. Also, in this method I would have to render the Tinsels and Tree together which will defeat the whole purpose of this question. https://imgur.com/39Dn9yU